# Interactive Jupyter Notebbok for Data Processing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've the following code running in my jupyter notebook:

```
import pandas as pd

class intData:
    
    def __init__(self, inputPath, fileName):
        
        self.inputPath = inputPath
        self.filename = filename
        
    def dataProcess(self, colNames, NewColnames, NewColnamesLog, val):
        
        df = pd.read_csv(self.inputPath + self.filename)
        df = df[colNames]
        
        for i, j, k  in list(zip(colNames, NewColnames, val)):
            
            df[j] = df[i] + k
            
        return df
            


finalDataProcess = intData(filepath, filename)

finalDataProcess = finalDataProcess.dataProcess(['A', 'B', 'C'], ['newA','newB','newC'], [2, 3, 4])
```

In this code, `filepath`, `filename`, `colnames`, `newColnames`, and `val` will change. So, I want to make it interactive. There will be drop down menu with list of `filepath`, `filename`, `colnames`, `newColnames`, and `val` (separately). And when we select them, we get the final output. This output will then be exported.

Can someone please guide me how to approach this problem? I would prefer it to be in jupyter notebook. But if it's not possible, then other python option will be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check out ipywidgets: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JussiNurminen: I first started with it. But didn't find good example in how to connect class objects with drop down menus. That's why I posted the question here. In case get some idea.

Comment: If ipywidgets is too limited for you, you probably need to move on to a full-on GUI library such as PyQt. This will allow you to do pretty much anything, but it's also quite complex to master.

Comment: Yeah! My process is not too big. So, I don't want to spend much time on complicated things.

Comment: @Beta, to work with a class, I'd just make a helper function that instantiates a class instance and returns whatever values you need. Then use ipywidgets' `interact`  (or any of the other variants) with that helper function.

Comment: @nedned: Can you please post a small example? It need not be as complex as my question. If I find it useful then mark it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Beta, did the example help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some good options to help you with this!

For a while, the canonical library to create mini reactive interfaces from your functions in your Jupyter notebooks has been [ipywidgets](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets) and is still a great option. You can also use [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) to convert notebooks containing these interfaces into dashboard web apps.

A more recent option, that allows you to make complex interfaces in your notebooks and even standalone dashboards is [Panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/).

There is also [Plotly Dash](https://github.com/plotly/dash), which, while being geared more towards making standalone web apps that feel a bit closer to working with the modern web platform, has the [jupyter-dash](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash) library that supports use in Jupyter Notebooks.

My advice would be to start with ipywidgets (maybe using Voila as well). If that doesn't do what you want, then try Panel or Dash.

Here's an example of how you can use `ipywidgets` with a class similar to yours:

```python
from ipywidgets import interact
import pandas as pd

class Foo:    
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
    def make_df(self, length):
        df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[self.a]*length, "b":[self.b]*length})         
        return df

@interact(a=[1,2,3], b=["x", "y", "z"], length=range(1,11))
def helper(a, b, length):
    foo = Foo(a, b)
    df = foo.make_df(length)
    return df
```

Comment: Yes. This is very helpful. Since I didn't get any answer for sometime, I stopped looking at the answer. So, I missed replying you. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!